# POST variable is not submitting dates from jQuery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to integrate fullcalendar into my php application.

However, I am having issues saving them to the database, the database was not accepting title and url unless they are in double quotes.

The start and the end date still come of as NULL. So when I refresh the data gets added to the database with the null value of the start and the end time elements.This raises concerns because, the moment I refresh the page all the events disappear from the calendar, when infact they are still in the database.

When I adjust the values of the null variables of the newly inserted event, all the events appear once again.

This is the ajax call in default.html.

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    var title = prompt('Event Title:');
    var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
    if (title) {
         var start = $.fullCalendar.moment(start);
         var end = $.fullCalendar.moment(end);
         console.log("Event Triggered");
         $.ajax({
                 url: 'add_events.php',
                 data: 'title='+ encodeURIComponent(title)+
                       '&start='+ encodeURIComponent(start)+
                       '&end='+ encodeURIComponent(end)+
                       '&url='+ encodeURIComponent(url),
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: 'text',
                success: function(json) {
                    alert('Added Successfully');
                 },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
         });
        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
             title: title,
             start: start,
             end: end,
             url:url,
             allDay: allDay
        },
            true // make the event "stick"
        );
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

And this is the add_events.php (Kindly note that this has no error except that it is not receiving the post.)

```
  <?php
   // Values received via ajax

        $data = $_POST;
  $json_array["title"]=json_decode($data["title"], true);
  $json_array["start"]=json_decode($data["start"], true);
  $json_array["end"]=json_decode($data["end"], true);
  $json_array["url"]=json_decode($data["url"], true);


  $title =$json_array["title"];
  $start =$json_array["start"];
  $end = $json_array["end"];
  $url = $json_array["url"];

  // connection to the database
 try {
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fullcalendar', '....',    '.......');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
   exit('Unable to connect to database.');
 }



   $sql = 'INSERT INTO  `evenement` ( `title`,`start`,`end`,`url`) VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ? )';
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute(array($title, $start, $end, $url )); 

  // check for errors
   if($stmt->errorCode() == 0) {
       $id = $pdo->lastInsertId(); 

   }
   else {
  // had errors
        $errors = $stmt->errorInfo();
        print_r($errors);
    }

?>
```

Any assistance how that could be achieved would be appreciated.

The Header of main file(default.html) looks like this :

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href='css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
 <link href='css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
 <script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
 <!--<script src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>-->
 <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
```

But the POST does not work for dates :-
I say this because I changed all fields to allow NULL but than it does allow NULL and creates a NULL, NULL, NULL,NULL entry in the database.

Comment: First thing: have you watched the ajax call in your web console to ensure the values are actually being passed?

Comment: @dgig
They are being passed ..as the console show, it comes in the `FormatData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things that could go wrong, so lets get started with the basics.

**STEP 1:-** Check if the `$_POST` variable is receiving the intended data. If dates are not reaching `php` then you know that you have to fiddle with the frontend `js`.

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();
```

**STEP 2:-** If the dates are reflecting inside the `$_POST` array, Maybe the date format is mismatching, Specially if the datatype of the date column inside the database is set to `DATETIME` since it expects the date to be in `"Y-m-d H:i:s"` format.

```
  $start =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($json_array["start"]));
  $end =date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($json_array["end"]));
```

Note:- this is just algorithmic code, and its not production ready, since a lot of checks shall be needed to make sure that no warning/error is thrown. eg. checking if the date string is not empty before passing it to `strtotime()` function.

**STEP 3:-** Maybe try `echo`ing out the mysql query that is being executed. etc.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting find...give me a few minutes, that could be something that is going wrong

Comment: The `FormatData` parameter in the Network Header tab shows this :
`title:"Some Title"
start:Thu Mar 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000
end:Fri Mar 11 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0000
url:"www.com"`

Comment: Which means that the date reception on the php end is not properly configured.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/pvxk05hmn/
We are almost there, look at how it is saving the date in the database.

Comment: Umm... Sorry, I cannot access that website since it is blocked inside my company, but I am sure you are proceeding in the right direction.

Comment: It is saving the date in the year 1969, thats the only issue now...any assistance with that so that I can wrap this up..thanks brother..

Comment: @UmarAftab are the dates that you entered the same that you mentioned above in comments?

Comment: @UmarAftab the code seems to be working with the value you provided as can be seen here. http://codepad.org/UIIYxzWR

Comment: I will do some digging

Comment: any better function I could use

Comment: @UmarAftab You can use `DateTime()` object, as shown here http://codepad.org/MgjlmUjL

Comment: BarakAllahu Feekum brother it worked like a charm, that is what I needed and I spend 2 weeks trying to break my head on this...Assalamalaikum

Comment: JazakAllah Khairan, you too. Wa-alaikumAssalaam :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are doing this:

`data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,`
                `

which is not the correct way to send parameters on a `POST`. This looks more like what you'd expect on a `GET` where the parameters are appended to the url. Instead, create an object and pass it to the data field:

```
var obj = {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   url: url
}
```

and then:

`data: obj`

Comment: I'll be interested to see, because I expect the query string format to work with the "dataType: 'text'" set as a parameter. Maybe he needs to do what you said, but change the dataType to "JSON"?

Comment: I tried with `data type: json` but it was not posting, so I was adviced to change it to `data type: text`

Comment: Yeah it does not post....I appreciate the assistance though...probably I am not explaining myself well here...

Comment: The issue right now if you see the above code is that the event is dynamic and the jquery is not picking up the start and the end data from the event itself.